# How to recover composer.json and composer.lock with installed.json?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project in PHP, but there is no composer.json and composer.lock –    only installed.json. How to recover composer.json and composer.lock with installed.json? Or with other way?

Comment: specify your project structure ? Any framework?

Answer (score 0):

just run `composer install`. The dependencies of your old composer.json are inside the installed.json. I don't know if that's the way to go as installed.json holds info for all the dependencies that were installed but if you are sure that it will be ok go ahead !!!

Comment: In such case Composer can't do anything, cause there is no `composer.json` file in path. Command `composer install` will exit with an error: `Composer could not find a composer.json file in ...`.